# Is there a way to do lossless compression for generated GIFs?

Tags: ios, gif, lossless-compression

We are using the following code to generate GIF file from a set of JPEG images, for the setting on doing lossless compression, it doesn't seem to generate a smaller sized file at all. Are we doing the right thing here?

```
CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pathUrl, CFSTR("com.compuserve.gif"), images.count, NULL);

// image/frame level properties
NSDictionary *imageProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:delayTime], (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime,
                                 nil];
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            imageProperties, (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary, 
                            nil];

for (UIImage *image in [images objectEnumerator]) {
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)properties);
}

// gif level properties
NSDictionary *gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0], kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality,
                               nil];
properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              gifProperties, (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary,
              nil];
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(imageDestination, (CFDictionaryRef)properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination);
CFRelease(imageDestination);
```

Comment: JPEG has about the best compression you can get (well JPG2 is better). Why do you want GIF? In any case I don't think you can find any other format PNG/GIF/TIFF that will compress like JPG can. Especially if you start with a JPG why would you change?

Comment: GIF files use lossless compression, and thus will typically result in larger file sizes than formats that use lossy compression like JPEG. Not sure what exactly you're after here...

Comment: we generate the GIF from set of JPEG files. trying to use compression on GIF to gain on file size. but the file size doesn't seem get changed after applying the kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality setting on the GIF image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GIF image format IS lossless compression.  However you are compressing a (lossy) compressed format.  File size may go up.

Comment: the file size didn't change at all, w/ or w/o the kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality setting on the GIF file

Answer (score 4):

GIF does not support the `kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality` property. No built in support for compressing gifs on iOS as far as I can tell -- I haven't been able to get the color map to work.

```
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount;
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime;
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap;
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap;
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime;
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/GIF_Dictionary_Keys

Answer (score 0):

Jpeg images contain many very similar but not identical pixels, which are very hard for lossless compression schemes to compress.  To get better compression you have to quantize the colors first.  Gif images will be lossless after you've taken the hit of losing information to make the image compressible.