# How to use kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality in saving GIF from video

Tags: ios, video, compression, gif

I am using the Regift (https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift) library to convert videos to GIFs, but I don't like how large the file size of the saved GIFs are. The library is using the `CGImageDestinationAddImage` function to add each frame of the video to a file, and one of the parameters of this function is a dictionary that lets you specify properties of the image, and one of the properties you can set is called `kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality` which I want to use to try to reduce the file size.

This is the original code in the library that defines the properties dictionary to be passed into the `CGImageDestinationAddImage` function:

```
let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String:
[
    kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: delayTime
]]
```

I'm trying to modify this dictionary to include the `kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality` property:

```
let frameProperties = [
kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String: 0.5,
kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String:
[
    kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: delayTime
]]
```

But when I try re-converting the same video file into a GIF, there is no difference in quality or file size, which means setting that property had no effect. Am I not setting it correctly? Or does this property just have no effect for GIF frames?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe that you can set the `kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality` for an animated gif (going off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19166700/1695900) answer). What you might be able to try is compressing or resizing the movie file before converting it to a gif.